# Should I Convert excel to csv or write htmltable to csv

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008, asp.net-mvc-3

I have 10 reports in my application which I let users to export to excel. I have never written CSV files. In my existing application, I convert the results from the stored procedure to an HTML table and write it to Excel.  Some of my results from the stored procedures have dynamic columns so I use dapper. My new requirement is to provide CSV export as well.

So should I first convert html datatable to excel and convert it to CSV or write HTML datatable to CSV. I dont want to manually parse because there are 10 different reports with different columns and some of the reports have dynamic columns so I cant manually parse.

**Stored procs returning Dapper, Dynamic Columns**

```
EFDbContext db = new EFDbContext();
        var recordDate = StartDate.Date;
        var cnn = new SqlConnection(db.Database.Connection.ConnectionString);
        cnn.Open();
        var p = new DynamicParameters();
        p.Add("@StartDate", StartDate);
        p.Add("@UserRoleID", UserRoleID);
        p.Add("@SelectedSystemIDs", SelectedSystemIDs);
        p.Add("@SelectedPartIDs", SelectedPartIDs);
        p.Add("@SelectedSubSystems", SelectedSubsystems);
        p.Add("@SelectedServiceTypes", SelectedServiceTypes);

    var obs = cnn.Query(sql: "spExportInstrumentConfigAll", param: p, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);

    var dt = ToDataTable(obs);

    return ExportDatatableToHtml(dt);


 public static DataTable ToDataTable(IEnumerable<dynamic> items)
        {
            if (items == null) return null;
            var data = items.ToArray();
            if (data.Length == 0) return null;

            var dt = new DataTable();
            foreach (var pair in ((IDictionary<string, object>)data[0]))
            {
                dt.Columns.Add(pair.Key, (pair.Value ?? string.Empty).GetType());
            }
            foreach (var d in data)
            {
                dt.Rows.Add(((IDictionary<string, object>)d).Values.ToArray());
            }
            return dt;
        }



public static string ExportDatatableToHtml(DataTable dt)
    {
        StringBuilder strHTMLBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        strHTMLBuilder.Append("<html >");
        strHTMLBuilder.Append("<head>");
        strHTMLBuilder.Append("</head>");
        strHTMLBuilder.Append("<body>");
        strHTMLBuilder.Append("<table border='1px' cellpadding='1' cellspacing='1 style='font-family:Garamond; font-size:medium'>");
    strHTMLBuilder.Append("<tr >");
    foreach (DataColumn myColumn in dt.Columns)
    {
        strHTMLBuilder.Append("<td >");
        strHTMLBuilder.Append(myColumn.ColumnName);
        strHTMLBuilder.Append("</td>");

    }
    strHTMLBuilder.Append("</tr>");


    foreach (DataRow myRow in dt.Rows)
    {

        strHTMLBuilder.Append("<tr >");
        foreach (DataColumn myColumn in dt.Columns)
        {
            strHTMLBuilder.Append("<td >");
            strHTMLBuilder.Append(myRow[myColumn.ColumnName].ToString());
            strHTMLBuilder.Append("</td>");

        }
        strHTMLBuilder.Append("</tr>");
    }

    //Close tags.  
    strHTMLBuilder.Append("</table>");
    strHTMLBuilder.Append("</body>");
    strHTMLBuilder.Append("</html>");

    string Htmltext = strHTMLBuilder.ToString();

    return Htmltext;

}
```

**Non-Dynamic Columns mapped to entity**

```
    return db.Database.SqlQuery<ServiceEntryPartExportDataRow>("[dbo].[spExportServiceParts] @parm1, @parm2, @parm3, @parm4,@parm5,@parm6",
                new SqlParameter("parm1", StartDate),
                new SqlParameter("parm2", EndDate),
                new SqlParameter("parm3", Reconciled),
                new SqlParameter("parm4", ServiceTypes),
                new SqlParameter("parm5", SelectedSystemIDs),
                new SqlParameter("parm6", UserRoleID)
                ).ToList().ToHTMLTable();

 public static string ToHTMLTable<T>(this IList<T> data)
    {
        PropertyDescriptorCollection props =
            TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(T));

    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

    builder.Append("<table border=\"1\">");

    builder.Append("<tr>");

    for (int i = 0; i < props.Count; i++)
    {
        builder.Append("<td>");

        PropertyDescriptor prop = props[i];

        builder.Append(prop.Name);

        builder.Append("</td>");
    }
    builder.Append("</tr>");

    object[] values = new object[props.Count];
    foreach (T item in data)
    {
        builder.Append("<tr>");

        for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
        {
            builder.Append("<td>");

            builder.Append(props[i].GetValue(item));

            builder.Append("</td>");
        }

        builder.Append("</tr>");

    }

    builder.Append("</table>");
    return "<html><body>" + builder.ToString() + "</body></html";
}
```

**Current code Sending to Excel**

```
return new PostActionResult(htmlTable, "ServiceEntryHistory", submit);

public PostActionResult(string htmlTable, string typeName, string submit) { this.htmlTable = htmlTable; this.typeName = typeName; this.submit = submit; }
        public PostActionResult(DataTable dataTable, string typeName, string submit) { this.dataTable = dataTable; this.typeName = typeName; this.submit = submit; }

        public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
        {
            if (submit == "Excel")
            {
                ExcelHelpers.ExportToExcel(context.HttpContext, typeName, htmlTable);
            }
            if (submit == "CSV")
            {
                ExcelHelpers.ExportToExcelCSV(context.HttpContext, typeName, htmlTable);

            }
        }

  public static void ExportToExcel(HttpContextBase httpBase, string fileNamePrefix, string table)
        {
            string TimeStamp = DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime().ToString();
            string fileName = string.Format("attachment;filename={0}_{1}.xls", fileNamePrefix, TimeStamp);
            httpBase.Response.ClearHeaders();
            httpBase.Response.ClearContent();
            httpBase.Response.Clear();
            httpBase.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", fileName);
            httpBase.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
            httpBase.Response.Write(table);
            httpBase.Response.End();
        }
```

Comment: Where is the actual structured data?  Exporting a collection of records to CSV is fairly trivial.  It's basically a loop and a string builder.  "Dynamic columns" isn't a problem.  If you have the column names, you print them as the first line of the file.  If you don't, you just print something else (like `Column{0}` with an incrementing integer).

Comment: You are using Office Interop in an ASP.NET environment, which is a [bad idea](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757). You should discontinue doing that, and use a library which is capable of generating the native Excel files you need without relying on Interop. If you search for "c# generate excel file" you should get plenty of useful libraries.

Comment: @David I posted my entire code. For reports with dynamic column(s) output I use dapper, For reports with non dynamic columns I have the entity mapped

Comment: @user721: The code to build a CSV is almost *identical* to the code to build the HTML table.  Only instead of HTML tags you would use commas, quotes (for values with commas in them, specifically), and carriage returns.  Aside from that, the structure is exactly the same.  In fact, CSV vs. HTML is a classic example of the Template Method Pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have code to build an HTML table from the data.  Building a CSV is very nearly identical.  For brevity, let's simplify the HTML table **pseudo-code**:

```
builder.Append("<table>");

// header
builder.Append("<tr>");
foreach (var column in columns)
    builder.Append("<th>" + column.name + "</th>");
builder.Append("</tr>");

// rows
foreach (var row in rows)
{
    builder.Append("<tr>");
    foreach (var column in row.columns)
        builder.Append("<td>" + column.value + "</td>");
    builder.Append("</tr>");
}

builder.Append("</table>");
```

Building a CSV is the exact same structure:

```
// header
foreach (var column in columns)
    builder.Append("\"" + column.name + "\",");
// there's now an extra comma at the end.  remove it, or use a
// different method to have built the row, such as string.Join.

// rows
foreach (var row in rows)
{
    foreach (var column in row.columns)
        builder.Append("\"" + column.value + "\",");
    // there's now an extra comma at the end.  remove it, or use a
    // different method to have built the row, such as string.Join.
    builder.Append(Environment.NewLine);
}
```

Remember that this is free-hand pseudo-code, there are some clean-ups you can employ.  You might also check the column types to determine if you need those escaped quotes or not, since numeric types wouldn't want them.  But the point is that the structure is the same.  A CSV is text in the same way that HTML is text.  It's only the dressing around the values that's different.

Side note: This is actually a classic example of the [Template Method Pattern](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Oz4_45DD8qU).